# Clipboard broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I know android broadcasts most of the events that occur one common is when battery is low or when there is an incoming call , I was wondering if there is some broadcast fired when some text is copied to the clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is some broadcast fired when some text is copied to the clipboard

No, sorry. You can register a listener with the `ClipboardManager`, but there is no system broadcast for clipboard events.

Comment: I want to to some task everytime something is copied to clipboard . Will service work ?

Comment: @DwijrajBhattacharyya: At best, you could use a foreground service to try to have it live forever. Users may not appreciate this, however.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I will try figure some better  way out :)